# Javascript/Jquery : Passing numbers entered in input tag separated with space to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to pass the numbers entered in the input tag to an array. Entered numbers will be separated with spaces.

```
var arr = [];
$(function(){

    var input = $('input').val(),
        button = $('button');
    button.on('click',function{
        arr = input.split(' ');
        console.log(arr);
    }); 

});
```

Sample Input : `1 4 3 5 65 145 6`

Desired Output : `arr = [1,4 3,5,65,145,6];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After split you get the array of `strings`. You need only after the splitting parse them into the number using **[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and [**parseFloat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) functions.

**Also one note**. If you start or end your input with `spaces` it will also give you a `NaN` in the array items, so at the end I filtered the array with values which are `not NaN`.

```js
var arr = [];

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var values = $('#inp').val();
  arr = values.split(' ').map(val => parseFloat(val)).filter(val => !Number.isNaN(val));
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" >
<button id="btn">Get values</button>
```

Comment: @PraveenBisht Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = '1 4 3 5 65 145 6';
var arr = input.split(' ').map(Number);
```

**result:**

arr = [1, 4, 3, 5, 65, 145, 6]

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

```
var outputArr = input.split( " " ).map( function(item){ return Number(item) });
```

or

```
var outputArr = input.split( " " ).map( function(item){ return +item });
```

or

```
var outputArr = input.split( " " ).map( function(item){ return parseInt(item) });
```

You need to iterate the **String** `item`s in the array and convert them to **Number**.

Comment: Another way to convert string to number is putting `+` in front of the string: `function(item){ return +item; }`